# IEEE Computer Science conference paper: Author order if equal contribution?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, authorship, ieee

We are four undergraduate students who have equally contributed to the research for a paper, each towards a different module. Will the co-author whose name is mentioned first be considered the one whose contribution was greatest? If we mention our names alphabetically, will all be considered equal contributors?
I ask because my name will be last alphabetically. Should we mention, or more specifically, is it allowed in an IEEE conference, that our contribution was equal?

Comment: Yes, in CS/EE, if your name comes first then it usually means you have contributed more.  In your case, I would put an asterisk or note to say that both of you have contributed equally.  I've seen this done for equal first authors, which is more important than those names listed at the back.